# Wordpress. Form specific function on each form submission to avoid another duplicate form submission

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.5.3, I have two forms with same input fields in a single page:

```
<form id="one" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <input name="movie" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button type="submit" name="submitone">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="two" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <input name="movie" type="hidden" value="2">
    <button type="submit" name="submittwo">Submit</button>
</form>
```

With the below function, I am able to save the above form data:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    save_data();
}
```

However, data is saved twice with the above code.
I have tried identifying the form which is submitted and save the data with below:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submitone'])) {
        save_data();
        }
    }
```

This is not working and not saving the form data.
How can I identify which form is submitted and save data?

**Edit 1**
Below the `save_data();` method:

```
// input variables
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$movie = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'movie');

// Table
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'names';

// Name ID
$default_row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($default_row != null) {
        $id = $default_row->id + 1;
    } else {
        $id = 1;
    }

// Names 
$data = array(
'id' => $id,
'name' => $name,
'movie' => $movie,
);

// INSERT DATA INTO THE TABLE
$new_name = $wpdb->insert($tablename, $data);
```

Comment: can you try printing POST data before you call save_data() and see what are you getting in post?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the input values.

Comment: so are you getting only one of the submit values or both of them?

Comment: also can you please show your save_data method?

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: you can check the submit value in save_data method. this way it will submit the data according to the form. right now you are checking for submit value outside the save_data method but when the method runs it can not identify the form submited.

Comment: Great if you can show me how can I check the form ID or Submit value in `save_data()`?

Comment: you can check if (isset($_POST['submitone'])) inside the save_data()

Comment: In that case, I have check for each form in the `save_data()` function. Is there a way I can check in the page itself in the `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {`?

Comment: not sure about that but you can check what parameters you are getting in $_SERVER, and if there is any way you can distinguise it.

Comment: but the main issue here is you are calling the common function for both forms and you also have the same name attribute for both of the forms so the save_data method does not know which form is been submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225013/discussion-between-theking-and-darsh-khakhkhar).

Comment: What action you are using to save the data? is it "init"? It must be saved on some WP action.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion - add hidden input field to forms with something that will help you identify it. Then, when one of this forms will be submitted, only it's hidden field will be given.

Example: `<input type="hidden" name="formn" value="1">` and then in `$_POST['formn']` you will have '1'.

Comment: Isn't `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` more correct way to check if the whole form is submitted than `(isset($_POST['formn']))` which checks only one input field?

Comment: To be honest I don't belive that using ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'``` is more correct than any other way of checking this. But my point was to use that one field to choose which one of forms was submitted, not to check if any of them was. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code.

The page template containing two form and the same page template is used to process Form Post method.

You might want to change the input field name 'name' and add a prefix to it to make it unique. ('my_name' in this code example) . Wordpress treats some field names in a form input as reserved keywords. WordPress behaves in strange way if you use any of the reserve names.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Form Template
 * Author: Meera Datey 
 * Template Post Type: post, page
 */

// Handle POST Submission here. 
if(isset($_POST['submitone'])) {

    print_r('First Form submitted');
    $my_name = $_POST['my_name'];
    // This should have input name  from first form
    print_r($my_name);
    save_data();
}
if(isset($_POST['submittwo'])) {
    print_r('Second Form submitted');
    $my_name = $_POST['my_name'];
    // This should have input name  from second form
    print_r($my_name);
    //save_data();
}

?>


<!-- This is a GET Request -->

<form  method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <input name="my_name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <button type="submit" name="submitone">Submit</button>
</form>

<form  method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <input name="my_name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <but
```

ton type="submit" name="submittwo">Submit

Answer (score 0):

You should use the wordpress core:

```
<form id="one" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <input name="movie" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitone">
    <button type="submit" name="submitone">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="one" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="My Name">
    <input name="movie" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitone">
    <button type="submit" name="submittwo">Submit</button>
</form>

function submitone_handle_form_submit() {
    // here $_POST

}

// Use your hidden "action" field value when adding the actions
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_submitone', 'submitone_handle_form_submit' );
add_action( 'admin_post_submitone', 'submitone_handle_form_submit' );

function submittwo_handle_form_submit() {
    // here $_POST

}

// Use your hidden "action" field value when adding the actions
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_submittwo', 'submittwo_handle_form_submit' );
add_action( 'admin_post_submittwo', 'submittwo_handle_form_submit' );
```